# How to Pass Data From One View to Another in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am quite new to Laravel

I have two views

- Book
- Read

**The `Book View` displays a single book**

```
<section class="cont-readingone">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-grid">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="cont-reading-image">
              <img src="{{ $book->image_url }}" alt="trending image" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="out-box">
              <h2>{{ $book->name }}</h2>
              <h3>{{ $book->author->name }}</h3>
              <br>
              <a href="#" class="start-btn">Start Reading</a><br><br>
              <a href="#" class="buy-btn"><img src="\images\cart-buy.png" width="13px"/>&nbsp; Buy</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

In my controller, I was able to achieve it using

```
    public function show(Book $book) {

        $relatedBooks = Book::where('author_id', $book->author_id)
  ->where('id', '!=', $book->id)
  ->get();

    return view('book')->with('book', $book)->with('relatedBooks', $relatedBooks);
     }
```

In my `web.php`

```
Route::get('/books/{book}', [BooksController::class, 'show'])->name('book');
```

> What I am trying to achieve is that, when I click **Start Reading** on
>   the Single Book Page, it takes me to another view page (`Read`) but it takes the book id that I clicked.

In the `Read View` I have this code,

```
    <script>
        "use strict";

        document.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (document.readyState == "complete") {
            window.reader = ePubReader("{{ $book->epub_url }}", {
               restore: true
             });
          }
        };

    </script>
```

> My problem  is that I don't know how to take the id of the book that I
>   click and Pass it to the `Read View`

I will be glad if someone can explain the logic to me as I am confused.

Comment: So, you have a page `Book View`, with a button `Start reading`, and when someone  clicks that button, he should be redirected to a view where there is the code you have posted?

Comment: You pass it to a route (via GET or POST), which passes it to a Controller method that can handle the parameter (via the request). Controller method passes the parameter to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To do via POST

```
//Book View
//change  <a href="#" class="start-btn">Start Reading</a> to
<form action="{{ route("your.route.to.read") }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   <input name="book_id " value ={{$book->id}} hidden>
   <button type="submit">Start Reading</button>
</form>

//your Route will be
Route::get('/read',YourReadController@yourFunction)->name('your.route.to.read');

//your controller will be 
public function yourFunction(Request $request)
{
    //book id is in $$request->book_id
    //your operation here
    return view('read')->with('data',$dataYouWantToSend);
}
```

> To do via GET

```
//Book View
    //change  <a href="#" class="start-btn">Start Reading</a><br><br> to
<a href="{{route("your.route.to.read", $book->id)}}" class="start-btn">Start Reading</a>

//route for get will be 
Route::get('/read/{book_id}',YourReadController@yourFunction)->name('your.route.to.read');

//your countroller will be 
public function yourFunction($book_id)
{
   //book id is in $book_id
   //your operation here
   return view('read')->with('data',$dataYouWantToSend);
}
```

Comment: Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong

In my controller, I have this
     public function read(Book $book_id)
     {

        $readBooks = Book::where('id', $book_id)->get();
        return view('read')->with('data', $readBooks);
    }


In my view, I tried to return it like this
                window.reader = ePubReader("{{ $readBooks->epub_url }}"

It's not working

Comment: In view, $data carries data to view not $readBooks. So you should use {{$data->epub_url}}.

Comment: Please, It returned this error Property [epub_url] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: This is my controller    public function read($book_id)
     {

        $readBooks = Book::where('id', $book_id)->get();
        dd($readBooks);
        return view('read')->with('data', $readBooks);
    }


<br/>
The  dd returned Collection {#378 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: looking at dd, no any item is being returned. When using get(), a collection is returned. [check documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-collections). So you have to loop inside to get the value. 

`foreach($readBooks as $readBook)
{
     $readBook->epub_url
}`

if you are sure that, only single tuple is returned then you can use 
`"$readBooks = Book::where('id', $book_id)->get()->first()"`

and use **$readBooks->epub_url** in the view

Comment: Thank you, this work         $readBooks = Book::where('id', $book_id)->get()->first();
and using {{ $data->epub_url }} in my view. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be helpful.